# php soap client call magento soap v2 api web service login method fail with Error cannot find parameter

Tags: magento

magento 1.6, php 5.3.8, windows 7, iis 7.5

follow the sample on mangento but can not get it work.

the old v1 api works though

last request is: string(233) " zzc000 "
last response is: string(294) " SOAP-ENV:ClientError cannot find parameter "

```
<?php
try{

    $proxy = new SoapClient('http://127.0.0.1/Magento1620/index.php/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1', array('trace' => 1, 'connection_timeout' => 120));

    $sessionId = $proxy->login("zzc000", "zzc000");

    $filters = array(
        'sku' => array('like'=>'zol%')
    );

    $products = $proxy->call($sessionId, 'product.list', array($filters));

    var_dump($products);       

    /*
    $proxy = new SoapClient('http://127.0.0.1:50594/webservice1.asmx?WSDL');

    var_dump($proxy->HelloWorld());
    */

} catch (Exception $e) {
    var_dump($proxy->__getLastRequest());
    var_dump($proxy->__getLastResponse());

    //echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    //var_dump($e->getTraceAsString());
}
?>
```

please help

thanks

---

I put web service as WS-I compliant v2 API WSDL
is it going to affect anything?

after a bit research, now i can log in using the following code, but i can not retrieve the products

```
$sessionId = $proxy->login(array(
        'username' => "zzc000",
        'apiKey' => "zzc000"
    ));
```

but I got the following exception when try to list the products

```
SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'sessionId' property
```

by using the following code

```
$filters = array(
        'sku' => array('like'=>'zol%')
    );

    $products = $proxy->catalogProductList($sessionId, $filters);
```

Comment: This was answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8867614/magento-ws-i-compliant-v2-api-wsdl-web-service-soap-error-encoding-object-has

Answer (score 0):

if you use the v2_soap api, the function call is slightly different. Instead of call() you have to use the camel-cased api method. e.g.:

```
$products=$proxy->catalogProductInfo($sessionId,$sku);
```

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8862288/1015655)
@sebastian_sch

the problem is that i can not even call login method to get start a session.
    '$sessionId = $proxy->login("zzc000", "zzc000");'
this call will through exception